# Algorithm for searching and calculating results from large amount of data

Tags: php, algorithm, search, google-distancematrix-api

I have a list of counselors from the Different city, states from the US and I'm calculation distance from one user to all counselors using the Google map API, and it's working, but sometimes it goes timeout because in some states we have many counselors and that could increase the execution time, one more note this App is written in PHP. Is there any algorithm available so I can reduce the execution time?

Comment: Are you returning all the distance to each counselors, or  you want to return only several counselors that near the user?

Comment: I'm returning only several counselors that near to the user but for that, i have to loop through all the counselors.